# Problem on Definite Integration and functions

Tags: definite-integrals, functional-equations

Q. The function f is continuous and has the property $f(f(x))=1-x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $$J = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$  then find $J$.

**My Attempt**- I have no clue to this problem! Instead I tried reorganising the functional equation as $$f(x) = 1- f^{-1}(x) $$,but I don't know any way to proceed from here. So am I doing good till now ? Or I have to do something else? Do you have any hint?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: $f$ is injective hence monotone.

Comment: I agree! But what is the advantage of that in calculating integral?

Comment: This is impossible if $f$ is continuous. So the advantage is that you cannot compute the integral because you cannot integrate the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example have $f(x) = x+m$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ and $f(x) = m + 1 - x$ for $m \le x \le m+1$, with $m > 1$ or $m < -1$, and $J = m + 1/2$.  So without some additional assumptions, $J$ is not determined.

Comment: Nice! But how could you say that $f(x)$ will be a linear function?

Comment: It doesn't have to be; these are just examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function: let $f(x)=f(y)$. Apply $f$ on both sides to get $1-x=1-y$, so $x=y$. Hence $f$ is one-to-one. Any one-to-one continuous function on strictly monotonic This makes $f\circ f$ strictly increasing but $1-x$ is strictly decreasing. Hence there is no such function $f$.

Comment: Ok , but is there is any chance that the integral would exist?

Comment: When the function does not exist how can its integral exist. The question is simply wrong.

Comment: Ok! I will look to it

Comment: This would be correct if you assumed $f$ maps $[0,1]$ into itself, or that the equation is true on all of $\mathbb R$.  But neither of those was stated.