# Function such that $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

Given that the function $f$ is continuous and has the property $f(f(x))=1-x$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Find $J=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.

My try:

I did this problem without finding the function $f(x)$, but I am interested in finding the function $f(x)$. So what I did is I replaced $x$ with $f^{-1}(x)$ in the given equation (I assumed $f^{-1}$ exists.):

$$\tag{1} f(x)=1-f^{-1}(x).$$

Also, by applying $f^{-1}$ on both sides of given equation

$$f(x)=f^{-1}(1-x).$$

Replacing $x$ with $1-x$,

$$f(1-x)=f^{-1}(x).$$

Substituting in $(1)$ I got

$$f(x)+f(1-x)=1.$$

This actually seemed to be a easier equation but I couldn't solve it. Particularly I think that it might be a piecewise function.

Comment: I don't think you will need to solve this, your effort has been well directed. Indeed, it seems that integrating the last equation from $0$ to $1$ and using a simple change of variable to show $\int_0^1 f(1-x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx$ should be giving the answer. If this works out, then do respond, but your effort was well directed. One small thing is, why is $f$ invertible? The point is that $f \circ f$ is bijective on $[0,1]$ so this is the clincher, although as the other comment points out you don't even need this!

Comment: Note that $1 - f(f(x)) = x$. Substituting $x=f(x)$ gives $1 - f(f(f(x))) = f(x)$. But $f(f(x))=1-x$, thus $1-f(1-x)=f(x)$, i.e., $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$. You do not need to assume invertibility.

Comment: @user20672 But your $f$ does not satisfy $f(f(x))=1-x$.

Comment: @Gary That's explained by the same logic that is used for numbers with the whole division by zero business , it also occurs in trigonometric equations. Basically, implications can very much add extraneous solutions. One of the steps is adding extraneous solutions, bonus for figuring it out.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon it actually worked,and also as I mentioned I figured out the value of $J$ .I am interested in finding $f(x)$.

Comment: @Learner So you want $f$ such that $f(x)+f(1-x) = 1$, or you want $f$ such that $f(f(x)) = 1-x$?

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon according to what I did,both are actually same?

Comment: @Learner In fact, this is not true. As mentioned, $f(x) = -x$ satisfies $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$, but *not* $f(f(x)) = 1-x$. The point is, that implications add solutions : there should be a step which you can't "reverse" and so you end up adding solutions which aren't solutions of the original equation.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon yes but what I assumed is that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists and as $f(x)=-x$ has a inverse the function should satisfy it? I mean all other implications I did are true if inverse exists?

Comment: Implications add solutions is a weird way of putting it. More generally the proof above has shown that $f(f(x)) = 1 - x \Rightarrow f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$. So any solution of  $f(f(x)) = 1 - x$ will be a solution of $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$, but has you haven't proved that (and infact it isn't true) $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1 \Rightarrow f(f(x)) = 1 - x$, the other way around isn't true. In common terminology, this is called necessary and sufficient conditions. The new equation is a necessary condition but not sufficient.

Comment: @Kaind Maybe in this context, yes I could have been more precise. But to be exact now : the implication $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1 \implies f^{-1}(1-x) = f(x)$ or $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1 \implies f(1-x) = f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't go through, as the counterexample shows. Anyway, the context of implications adding solutions is probably better reserved for numbers and trigonometric equations (extraneous solutions), but I just brought the same thing forward for functions, where extraneous solutions are created from following irreversible steps (not a bad thing, of course, provided you can throw the bad apples out).

Comment: @Learner I showed in my comment above that you do not need to assume that the inverse exists to conclude $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$.

Comment: @Gary You can show that $f$ is monotone, and hence inverse on some subset of $[0,1]$ exists.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon $f(x)=-x$ Is not satisfying because it is not satisfying eq($1$) which means that our function must satisfy both eq($1$) and last one

Comment: Let me just put it out there: The solutions for $f(x) + f(1-x) = 1$ are precisely all solutions which satisfy $f(x) = g(x) , 0.5 < x \le 1 ; 1/2 , x = 1/2 , 1 - g(1-x) , 0 \le x < 0.5$, where $g(x)$ is any continuous function on $[0.5,1]$ satisfying $g(0.5) = 0.5$. However this is not the solution set for $f(f(x)) = 1-x$.

Comment: @Learner So do you want to find a function that satisfies eq (1)? That's related to the *functional square root* of a function, which talks about : given $g(x)$, when does there exist an $f$ such that $f(f(x)) = g(x)$? For that, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/characterising-functions-f-that-can-be-written-as-f-g-circ-g/1122#1122) is useful. Of course, the square root is not going to be *continuous*, however : if $f(f(x)) = 1-x$ then $f$ is injective and hence monotone, but then $f(f(x))$ has to be monotone increasing.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon can you explain what does the answer in the link meant by "there are an even number of cycles of f of any given even length"

Comment: duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820310/886804

Comment: @IITM Perhaps you would like to come to my chatroom, since this place may not be right to discuss it? The chatroom link is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119549/teresa-lisbon-senior-agent-cbi), and we can discuss that answer in length there.

Answer (score 1):

In absence of continuity there are infinitely many such function.
Pick g a HAMEL function (for which g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y) )
Then $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{g(1)}$ satisfies
$f(x)+f(1-x)=\frac{g(x)+g(1-x)}{g(1)}=\frac{g(x+1-x)}{g(1)}=1$